# Is it possible to cluster polygons in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, clustering

Is it possible to cluster polygons in Leaflet?

In a similar way to the [Marker Cluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) plugin

Answer (score 3):

You would probably be interested in this post:

[Feature Request - Ability to cluster polygons (Leaflet.markercluster issue #612)](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/issues/612)

> You might be interested in [Leaflet.Deflate plugin](https://github.com/oliverroick/Leaflet.Deflate), but be careful when removing the marker (see [#580](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/issues/580)).
>
> Another possibility would be to "add" methods `getLatLng` and `setLatLng` to your polygons, so that MCG can handle them like points. But the result might not be like what you expect, as the polygons would cluster based on the position of their center (or whatever position you return through `getLatLng`), not on their shape.
>
> […]
>
> Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/237/

Instead of using regular `L.polygon`, you would first create a custom class and use it to instantiate your shapes. In the below code, we customize `L.rectangle`, but you can do the same for other vectors.

```js
// Create a new vector type with getLatLng and setLatLng methods.
// Of course you can do the same with other polygons.
L.RectangleClusterable = L.Rectangle.extend({
  _originalInitialize: L.Rectangle.prototype.initialize,

  initialize: function (bounds, options) {
    this._originalInitialize(bounds, options);
    this._latlng = this.getBounds().getCenter(); // Define the polygon "center".
  },

  getLatLng: function () {
    return this._latlng;
  },

  // dummy method.
  setLatLng: function () {}
});
```