# Clustering polygon's created with Leaflet.Draw

Tags: leaflet, geometry, clustering, markers, leaflet-draw

I am experimenting with Leaflet at the moment and am trying to cluster polygon's that I've created with Leaflet.Draw plugin's tools. I know that clustering polygons is possible ([Is it possible to cluster polygons in Leaflet?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/197882/is-it-possible-to-cluster-polygons-in-leaflet)) and have successfully clustered polygons that I've created manually by creating an extended ClusterablePolygon class. I can also cluster markers that are created by Leaflet.Draw. This brings a twofold question:

1. Is it possible to alter the draw tools in such way that it automatically creates a custom ClusterableGeometry instead of a regular geometry?
2. Is it possible to instantly after creation convert a regular geometry into ClusterableGeometry?